# DbContext object not working from within loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my `ActionMethod`, it does not populate data to database.

```
private StudentDBContext db = new StudentDBContext();

public ActionResult PopulateData()
        {
            Student objStu = new Student();

            for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                objStu.ID = i+1;
                objStu.name = "something";
                db.Students.Add(objStu);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }


            return View();
        }
```

Only time when it does is when I use it without loop(as shown below) why is that so?

```
public ActionResult PopulateData()
        {
            Student objStu = new Student();

            //for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            //{
                objStu.ID = 1;
                objStu.name = "something";
                db.Students.Add(objStu);
                db.SaveChanges();
            //}


            return View();
        }
```

Comment: try putting `Student objStu = new Student();` inside the loop.

Comment: You don't get any updates with the loop or you only get one update with the loop?

Comment: I don't get any update @MikeCheel

Comment: I would think your original code would first add a student to the database and then the second time through the loop it would update the first record it put in. Is that not happening?

Comment: no its not happening @MikeCheel

Comment: when you run your app are you recreating the database each time?

Comment: No I don't, only persisting by using codefirst technique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are adding the same student over and over again. Instead, create the new student (objStu) inside the loop:

```
public ActionResult PopulateData()
{        
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        Student objStu = new Student();
        objStu.ID = i+1;
        objStu.name = "something";
        db.Students.Add(objStu);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: This is because when you add the `objStu` object to the context, it is "tracked".  Any future changes to this object will be persisted with `db.SaveChanges()` is called.